# Модель для десериализации простейшего XML

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация

Всем привет! Необходимо десериализовать xml простейшего вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<requestID>057f4c78-a022</requestID>
```

Модель нижеследующего вида возвращает пустой результат:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("requestID")]
public class RequestId
{
    public string RequestID { get; set; }
    RequestId() { }
}
```

Понимаю, что модель некорректная, но не понимаю как правильно описать содержимое узла requestID.

Десериализую так:

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RequestId));
StringReader xmlString = new StringReader(responseString);
RequestId orderStatus = (RequestId)deserializer.Deserialize(xmlString);
```

Comment: ну так вы покажите, как вы сериализуете\десериализуете, какие проблемы с этим у вас, что не получается?

Comment: Проблема не в десериализации, а в корректности построения модели. Десериализую так:
`XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RequestId));
StringReader xmlString = new StringReader(responseString);
RequestId orderStatus = (RequestId)deserializer.Deserialize(xmlString);`
где responseString - представленный выше xml

Comment: Пустой конструктор без параметров при объявлении класса можно опустить, компилятор по умолчанию создает такой конструктор, если он не реализован.

Comment: @Anamnian, но не приватный, наверное?

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, но тогда вопрос к автору- зачем у него был определен приватный конструктор? Закрытый конструктор — это особый конструктор экземпляров. Обычно он используется в классах, содержащих только статические элементы. Если в классе один или несколько закрытых конструкторов и ни одного открытого конструктора, то прочие классы (за исключением вложенных классов) не смогут создавать экземпляры этого класса.

Comment: @Anamnian Это требование при сериализации xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам подойдет такой класс:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "requestID")]
public class RequestID
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Дело в том, что по умолчанию все свойства/поля класса представляются как `XmlElement`, если вам нужно что-то отличное, то необходимо указать это явно.