# как через массив добавить и удалить элементы в документ xml в c#?

Tags: c#, xml

Мне нужно добавить в готовый xml файл новые элементы  (не больше 5) c новым id элементов и в случай необходимости удалить их, вот файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<request>
    <auth id="1" toAmount="20">  </auth>
</request>
```

что должно получиться

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<request>
<auth id="1" toAmount="20">  </auth>
<auth id="2" toAmount="20">  </auth>
<auth id="3" toAmount="20">  </auth>
<auth id="4" toAmount="20">  </auth>
<auth id="5" toAmount="20">  </auth>
</request>
```

как добавить новые элементы с последовательно меняющимся id (от 1 до 5) и удалить 4 последних добавленных элементов

Comment: В принципе можно ничего не писать, потому что в описанном сценарии программа ничего не делает)

Comment: Ну а вы хоть как-то уже пробовали?

Comment: а что вы знаете про сериализацию(https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/6.4.php) xml?

Comment: можно сказать что это еще и дубликат этого вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/868948/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-xml